# Find the Point on the Spline curve

Tags: geometry, spline

Imagine I have a bezier curve infact a cardinal spline curve which is drawn using beziersegment. It is a piecewise curve segment which takes one actual points and two control points. I have the spline curve. But my requirement is to get a point on the curve.

I have followed the method below to achieve it.

Formula : P(t) = s(-t3 + 2t2 – t)P1 + s(-t3 + t2)P2 + (2t3 – 3t2 + 1)P2 + s(t3 – 2t2 + t)P3 + (-2t3 + 3t2)P3 + s(t3 – t2)P4

where P is the point on the curve,P1,P2,P3,P4 are the actual points, s is the tanget and it is inversely  proportional to t. and t is the tension. I calculate P(t)x and P(t)y co ordinates for the t varying from 0 to 1.

But these points are approximate. Not exact. I need to get the exact position on the curve.

Can anyone suggest me any methods with which I can find the point on the curve?

Or how the points are drawn using the actual points and control points?

Regards,
Sharmila

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly you can-t find the exact position. The anticipated points is an approximation over multiple points, where every of this point on the function is counted in by a ratio, depending on the distance to the interpolated point.